# How do I force all requests to use https on a custom domain in appengine?

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, python-2.7, https

I already have my certificate set up. http://www.example.com and https://www.example.com both works.

However, I want to route all traffic from http://www.example.com to go to https://www.example.com.

How can I do that with appengine? I'm using Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your app.yaml:

```
handlers:

- url: YOUR_URL
  script: YOUR_SCRIPT
  secure: always
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an older post but I kept coming across it when trying to figure out how to do this myself with the most recent GAE Flex environment. We're using Django and the headers/keys we had to use to get SSL forced were:

```
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 31536000  # - One Year
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True

SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Extracted from [Google document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Secure_URLs)

```
handlers:
- url: /youraccount/.*
  script: accounts.py
  login: required
  secure: always
```

> always - Requests for a URL that match this handler that do not use HTTPS are automatically redirected to the HTTPS URL with the same path. Query parameters are preserved for the redirect.